# Launching Electron on Ubuntu WSL

Tags: root, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemctl, sandbox

I am running a WSL2 Ubuntu system. I'm attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) to launch an Electron boilerplate.

When running yarn dev I come across this error:

> [14143:0218/164010.657008:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /home/alex/final-project/test/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755

Running with `--no-sandbox` yields the same error.

I have attempted changing the systemctl: `sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1` which does not work on WSL. I attempted to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/shayne/wsl2-hacks) to gain access to systemctl.

This did not work, with the PowerShell commands being outdated and `systemctl is-active dbus` returning:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
>
> Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the error message tells you what to do, there is a `chrome-sandbox` file in the directory it shows, you need to use chroot and chown to give it the proper owner and permissions.

```
sudo chown root: home/alex/final-project/test/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 home/alex/final-project/test/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox
```

Comment: my error message shows 4755, not 4577

Comment: yeah my bad, i'm a bit dyslexic :| - fixed